# I cannot convert successfully VMWare Fusion to Paralles

Tags: macos, vmware, vmware-fusion, parallels

I have a macOS host and macOS virtual machine on VMWare with the extension `.vmwarevm` and I wanted to convert it to `.pvm` Parallels Extension. Parallels was able to do that but it didn't detect any OS on VMWare file and it stuck on booting. Tutorials that I found are not very detailed and I do not know what I could have missed. I know that is possible and I managed to do that in the past, but eventually, maybe someone has an idea of what is broken.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In parallels: Open file > choose .vmwarevm file > convert.